# Uploading Large Files to WCF from Xamarin Android App Crashes

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, wcf, xamarin

I'm trying to upload a large video (1 GB+) from my xamarin app and it keeps crashing once it reaches about 0.5 GB of my file. The only way I've found to get the videos to post to my WCF service while sending data along with it is using the MultiPart logic but I'm not sure if I'm running out of memory or what because even in debug mode, it simply crashes without any real error message.

I'm trying to run it on a native device (not a sim) and it's a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 9.

Here's the upload code that I'm using: (p.s. - as a test, I tried putting the WriteAsync into a for loop thinking that maybe trying to write the whole gig was the problem, but the result was the same. That's why you'll see the MAXFILESIZEPART constant in there which is just an int equal to 10000000.)

```
private async Task<byte[]> GetMultipartFormDataAsync(Dictionary<string, object> postParameters, string boundary)
        {
            try
            {

                using (Stream formDataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    bool needsCLRF = false;

                    foreach (var param in postParameters)
                    {
                        // Thanks to feedback from commenters, add a CRLF to allow multiple parameters to be added.
                        // Skip it on the first parameter, add it to subsequent parameters.
                        if (needsCLRF)
                            await formDataStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n"), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("\r\n"));

                        needsCLRF = true;

                        if (param.Value is FileParameter)
                        {
                            FileParameter fileToUpload = (FileParameter)param.Value;

                            // Add just the first part of this param, since we will write the file data directly to the Stream
                            string header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\"\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n",
                                                boundary,
                                                param.Key,
                                                fileToUpload.FileName ?? param.Key,
                                                fileToUpload.ContentType ?? "application/octet-stream");

                            await formDataStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(header));

                            // Write the file data directly to the Stream, rather than serializing it to a string.
                            if (fileToUpload.File.Length > MAXFILESIZEPART)
                            {
                                for (var i = 0; i < fileToUpload.File.Length; i += MAXFILESIZEPART)
                                {
                                    var len = i + MAXFILESIZEPART > fileToUpload.File.Length
                                        ? fileToUpload.File.Length - i
                                        : MAXFILESIZEPART;
                                    await formDataStream.WriteAsync(fileToUpload.File, i, len);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await formDataStream.WriteAsync(fileToUpload.File, 0, fileToUpload.File.Length);
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string postData = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}",
                                                  boundary,
                                                  param.Key,
                                                  param.Value);
                            await formDataStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(postData));
                        }
                    }

                    // Add the end of the request.  Start with a newline
                    string footer = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
                    await formDataStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(footer), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(footer));

                    // Dump the Stream into a byte[]
                    formDataStream.Position = 0;
                    byte[] formData = new byte[formDataStream.Length];
                    formDataStream.Read(formData, 0, formData.Length);

                    return formData;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And it's eventually failing on the following line

```
await formDataStream.WriteAsync(fileToUpload.File, i, len);
```

but only after a certain point (about 500MB) so I'm assuming it's a memory issue but it doesn't say so. Is there a better way to accomplish this task? I'm doing it so that it also records the progress as the upload happens. I'm trying to accomplish something similar to uploading large videos via the facebook app so that it will upload in the background while you continue working. It works great when working with smaller files (i.e. - < 500 MB) but this is the first time I've tried a file that was almost a gig in size.

NOTE: This happens BEFORE it starts posting anything to the server so it's not IIS or WCF related. This code crashes just writing the bytes to the memory stream.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: there are many config setting for IIS/WCF that limit the size of requests.  I suggest you look at those.  I'd also check the IIS logs.

Comment: This happens BEFORE it starts posting anything to the server. This code crashes just writing the data to a memory stream.

Comment: I'm not sure that transmitting a 1 GB file as a single request is ever going to work very well - irrespective of whether you fix this particular error or not

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the service will stop at a certain time point, and because the file you transfer is about 1G, it is likely to be sendtimeout.No transfer completed within the specified time, causing exception。The SendTimeout that specifies how long the write operation has to complete before timing out. The default value is 1 minute.

[image]

I set sendtimeout to 15 seconds in my configuration file.If the data takes more than 15 seconds, an exception will occur. You can set it to a higher value to avoid timeout and exception.

For information about sendtimeout, please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.sendtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

**UPDATE**

I think it might be a memory overflow problem.Large file may cause memory overflow, unable to read at the same time.

You can refer to the following links for solutions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johan/are-you-getting-outofmemoryexceptions-when-uploading-large-files

Comment: This happens BEFORE it starts posting anything to the server. This code crashes just writing the data to a memory stream.

Comment: I update my reply,I think it may be a memory overflow problem.